# Update data validation using VBA when cell is selected?

Tags: vba, excel

I have VBA-code that updates the data validation list in a cell.

```
Sub SetDataValidationList(r As Range, s As String)
    Dim dv As Validation
    Set dv = r.Validation

    With dv
        .Delete
        .Add Type:=xlValidateList, AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, Operator:=xlBetween, Formula1:=s
    End With
End Sub
```

I want the data validation list to be up to date whenever the cell is selected. I know that I can run the subroutine above in the Worksheet_Change event. But is there any event like Cell_Select? Or some way I can emulate an event like this.

Comment: Yes there is an **Event** for *Selection*

Comment: Avesome, are you refering to Worksheet_SelectionChange? I have needed this for more than a year, but didn't know that it existed.

Comment: Start here:  http://www.cpearson.com/Excel/Events.aspx